# How to normalize the html document from webpage in node.js environment, such as tbody?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome

I have a page downloaded from a website page, which have a table tag without tbody, but I can see the tbody tag in chrome browser. Obviously the html document have been normalized by chrome. I want to normalize the web page document using some npm package to have the same effect as chrome.

Which npm package can do it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a tool like this and for a reason.

Because the "normalization" you are talking about isn't mandatory for HTML to be valid. `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` are not required.

**But why do browsers do it?**

It is added because it is needed to build the DOM tree.

Here is how the parser works:

> **8.2.5.4.9 The "in table" insertion mode**
>
> A start tag whose tag name is one of: "td", "th", "tr"
>
> Insert an HTML element for a "tbody" start tag token with no
>   attributes, then switch the insertion mode to "in table body".

More here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable

---

Btw a really easy way to do it is use search and replace.

**Search**: `<table>`

**Replace**: `<table><tbody>`

And after:

**Search**: `</table>`

**Replace**: `</tbody></table>`